# Erro ao utilizar um bot no python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, chatbot, chatterbot

Sempre que rodo o seguinte codigo(usando python)

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

bot = ChatBot('bot1')
bot = ChatBot(
    'bot1',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3'
)

conversa = ListTrainer(bot)
conversa.train([
    'Olá',
    'Oi',
    'Qual o seu nome?',
    'bot1',
    'Prazer em te conhecer',
    'Igualmente',
])
while True:
    try:
        resposta = bot.get_response(input("Usuário: "))
        if float(resposta.confidence) > 0.5:
            print("bot1: ", resposta)
        else:
            print("Eu não entendi :(")
    except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

recebo essa mensagem de erro

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\guppe\bot1\python3 bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = ChatBot('bot1')
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0-py3.9.egg\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0-py3.9.egg\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0-py3.9.egg\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 22, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo seu log de erro, você está utilizando Python 3.9.

Olhando a documentação do [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html), a função `time.clock()` foi descontinuada na versão 3.3 e removida na versão 3.8, o que provavelmente é a origem do seu erro.

Como você não tem fácil acesso para edição da biblioteca que usa este método (assim, você poderia utilizar os métodos `time.perf_counter()` ou `time.process_time()` como substitutos para versões de Python 3.8 ou mais), creio que a solução mais fácil seria você fazer um *downgrade* da sua versão do Python para alguma anterior à versão 3.8.